# How to use attribute as filter?

Tags: magento-1.9, filter, magento-community

I want to create attributes which can be used as filter.

eg: there are three attributes model-number, width, aspect ratio.

When I choose a particular option from model-number, the width and aspect ratio of that model-number should be available to select from the `width` and `aspect ratio` attribute's dropdown.

Site for reference is : [this site](http://www.blackcircles.com/order/tyres/search)

Answer (score 0):

Create attributes in the admin under `Catalog->Attributes->Manage Attributes.`

While creating them set the value `Use In Layered Navigation` as `Filterable (with results)`. Once this is done, you will have to simply use ajax calls to update data in width and aspect ratio when the user changes model-number. You will have to use `onchange` function in your js and make controllers to fetch the data.